# New Ryzen laptop - suspend = panic, is a fix in the pipeline?

Tags: ubuntu, hardware, suspend, laptop, panic

As though I had not had some 10 years of on-and-off Linux experience, I patiently awaited the release of laptops with the new AMD Ryzen "APU" chips, planning to install Linux, after speculative execution vulnerabilities made Intel look bad. So I bought the shiny new Lenovo IdeaPad 720s 13" AMD Ryzen 5 edition, which would be a perfect laptop if it worked.

I installed elementary OS Loki (reskinned Ubuntu), got everything up and running (except Wifi), and closed the laptop. I opened it again to see a blank console with the infamous blinking cursor. So like anyone else trying to run Linux a new laptop, I installed the newest kernel (as of mid-January) which was a dramatically improved experience from four years ago (last time), booted up Elementary again, closed the laptop, opened it, and... screen turned off. Reboot indicated an unclean shutdown. After I reproduced the issue a couple of times, my Lenovo recovery partition kicked in, deleted GRUB, and booted into Windows.

I was definitely going to post this question/bug report earlier, but I'm lazy. Sorry. Has anyone else had success running Linux on a Ryzen laptop? Is there a bug report open? Suspend issues are usually a kernel thing, right? Should I open a bug somewhere (after trying the newest kernel)?

Comment: disable Secure Boot in the BIOS?
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_IdeaPad_720s_(Ryzen)

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Ubuntu-on-Ideapad-720s/td-p/3817545

try other ubuntu